# Приложение вылетает, когда удаляется значение child firebase

Tags: android, firebase-database

```
basket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                database.child(productList.get(i).getDestnumber()).child(productList.get(i).getName()).child(productList.get(i).getPrice()).setValue("1").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            database.child(productList.get(i).getDestnumber()).child(productList.get(i).getName()).child(productList.get(i).getPrice()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    productList.get(i).setCount(Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)));
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                basket.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int a = productList.get(i).getCount();
                a++;
                database.child(productList.get(i).getDestnumber()).child(productList.get(i).getName()).child(productList.get(i).getPrice()).setValue(String.valueOf(a));
            }
        });
        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int a = productList.get(i).getCount();
                a--;
                if (a == 0){
                    count.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    basket.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    database.child(productList.get(i).getDestnumber()).child(productList.get(i).getName()).child(productList.get(i).getPrice()).removeValue(); //вылетает приложение после этого действия
                }else{
                    database.child(productList.get(i).getDestnumber()).child(productList.get(i).getName()).child(productList.get(i).getPrice()).setValue(String.valueOf(a));
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: 1. Куча `productList.get(i)` явно лишняя. Ссылку из `productList.get(i)` сохраните в переменную и ту переменную подсовываете. 2. Непонятная переменная `i` вызывает вопросы. Возможно, значение в ней меньше 0 или больше максимального индекса productList. 3. Вангую, что исключением будет NPE или выход за пределы массива, а чтобы точно знать, вам следовало к вопросу приложить стеки сключения